# Removing first simbol in each Array line from the dataTextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have an array from the dataTextBox field (3 lines).
And I need to delete first symbol in each line.
I'm trying to do it with only line line, but I cannot. This code doesn't do anything.
How to write correct code? Thank You!

```
var lines = this.dataTextBox.Lines; 
var sLines = Convert.ToString(lines[0]); //Converting first line to "String".
char[] ch = sLines.ToCharArray();        //Converting first line to "CharArray".
char s = sLines[0];                      //I took the first letter from first line.
string x = Convert.ToString(s);     //Converting to "String" the first letter from first line.
string b = x.Replace(x, "");       //Replacing the first letter from first line on "" symbol.
this.dataTextBox.Lines = lines.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.dataTextBox.Lines = this.dataTextBox.Lines.Select(s => s.Substring(1)).ToArray();
```

By the way... your code **does** something, but you assign `lines` to `this.dataTextBox.Lines` although you never changed `lines`. The change is in `b` only...

Comment: lol... post identical answer 3 minutes later, and a checkmark for your troubles...

Comment: Sorry it seems I was typing too slowly... :)

Comment: No worries. It's honestly funny. :)

Answer (score 5):

```
this.dataTextBox.Lines =
    this.dataTextBox.Lines.Select(x => x.Substring(1)).ToArray();
```

This will project each line onto the same line without the first character, and then convert everything back to an array so it can be assigned back to `Lines`.

Note that this assumes all lines have at least one character; it will throw an exception if that's not the case. You can add a `.Where(x => x.Length > 0)` before the `Select()` if that's a concern.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure whether you meant simply trimming the first character, or removing all occurrences of the first character in each line.  dlev's answer covers the first case, this covers the second:

```
this.dataTextBox.Lines = 
    this.dataTextBox.Lines.Select(x => x.Replace(x[0], "").ToArray()
```